# Rigth border of the ListView like in Gmail app

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and current item is shown with an arrow to the right like this:

[image]

I want to add the right border. Right now I can do it just with padding like this:

[image]

but then the selected item also has a border. Gmail app somehow does it properly:

[image]

Can someone give suggestions how to implement this feature?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Please provide a full image of the UI you are requiring and show the full image of UI you have designed till now. We are not understanding, what difference you are pointing to..

Comment: Hi, it's a standard app with a list on the left and details fragment on the right. The difference is in the border between list and details.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not very specific to your query.

But hope that you are trying to create some thing like [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Check that out.

Kindly let me know if you need some thing else than that.

Comment: it's not about drawer, it's about ListView

Comment: Sorry .. I am exactly not getting your query. :(